# complete border right in css

Tags: html, css

I have this HTML

```
.container_1
{
    width: 80%;
    border: 5px solid black;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.container_2
{
    float: left;
    border: 5px solid red;
    width: 100%;                    
}

.container_1
{
    width: 80%;
    border: 5px solid black;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.container_2
{
    float: left;
    border: 5px solid red;
    width: 100%;                    
}

<div class="container_1">
    <div class="container_2">
    Content 1
    </div>
    <div class="container_2">
    Content 2
    </div>    
</div>​
```

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/uZVnB/3/

The problem is that as you see in fiddle the border of .container_1 overlaps the border to the border of .container_2 , so is any form that show complete the border of both containers

Answer (score 4):

Remove `float` & `width` from 
`.container_2`. Write like this:

```
.container_2
{
    border: 5px solid red;   
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/uZVnB/4/

Comment: width 100% + border = more than 100%, that's why the border is cropped.

Comment: @ShogunArts.de that i know but in this question there is no need for float & width:100%. You got the desire result without it.

Comment: @ShogunArts.de but if you want the desire result with float & width:100%, then you can use css box-sizing property. Check this http://jsfiddle.net/uZVnB/14/

Comment: Yeah, I know. Was just an explanation for eli.rodriguez why the border wasn't displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Change the width of `.container_2` from 100% to 98%, and everything will be fine. When you set its width to 100%, naturally, it will expand to the maximum, and the borders will overlap.

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove `float: left` and `width: 100%`, since block element fills the entire width of its container, it works fine.
2. If you have to use `float: left` style (although I don't think it is required since you have a `width: 100%` which makes float not behaving as it is defined), you could use `box-sizing: border-box`, but it only works for mordern browsers, lower version of IE does not support this property.
3. You may also use `position: absolute; left: 0; right: 0;` to absolutely position it, but it also conflicts with `float: left` style and IE6 does not support it.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by using CSS attribute `box-sizing:border-box;`

[**SEE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/akhurshid/6Awkb/)

**CSS:**

```
.container_1 {
    width:80%;
    border:1em solid;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.container_2 {
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box; /* Safari */
    width:100%;
    border:1em solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering IE in mind, here is my solution.
The border will always be extra than the 100% width.

Here is the solution http://jsfiddle.net/uZVnB/41/

Hope this helps